Keycloak 24.0.5 clustering not working on Azure
I am using keycloak 24.0.5 and i installed it on 2 VMs that are behind Application Gateway on Azure. When i start both of them application is not working. When i stop 1 and run 1 everything works.
Since I have already AG as proxy this is my configuration on keycloak :
proxy=edge hostname-strict=false hostname-strict-https=false http-enabled=true
I also added cache=ispn. When i run my servers i get this messages :
INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [...] INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000079: Channel ISPNlocal address is... WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state
This means that clusters found each other but still application is not working. Is there anything i missed?
